# Strange contentSize in UIScrollView of ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I add a scrollview as a subview by using the storyboard.

here is my code

```
[self.bottomScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bottomScrollView.bounds];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.bottomScrollView addSubview:v];
[self.bottomScrollView setContentSize:v.frame.size];
```

in which self.bottomScrollView is the subview which is added by storyboard.
I think because the contentsize is equal to the view v and the frame of v start from (0,0), the scrollview should not be able to be moved either horizontally or vertically.

However, the result is quite strange, the bottomScrollView still can be scrolled viertically as the following image shows.(this is not the bounce)
[image]

Acutally, I tried add a scrollview programly and it works correct.
Why this happens? Any bugs of storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set NO to self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property, then the scrollview won't show such a "strange" offset

Answer (score 0):

contentSize of your bottomScrollView should have been changed after you set it with code. Try to move the code  setting contentSize of bottomScrollView to viewWillAppear:

Comment: I have checked in viewwillappear or viewdidappear, contentSize is still equal to what I have set